# c++ get vertex arrays from buffer (glTF model loader)

Tags: c++, buffer, vertex-buffer, gltf

I am using https://github.com/syoyo/tinygltf to load glTF model. glTF models have a buffer that includes the position datas (vertex coordinates). I want to print these coordinates to the screen.

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.meshes.size(); ++i)
    {
        Mesh &gltfmesh = model.meshes[i];
        Primitive &prim = gltfmesh.primitives[i];
        Accessor& acess = model.accessors[prim.attributes["POSITION"]];
        BufferView& bview = model.bufferViews[acess.bufferView];
        Buffer& bfer = model.buffers[bview.buffer];

        // cout << bfer.data ... I need to cout the vertex arrays somehow
    }
```

As you can see the coordinates are in the `Buffer& bfer` now I want to extract them into Vec3F structures (one Vec3F struct has 3 variables: `float x, y, z`), or anything that I can print it.

Also I need to mention that the buffer not just includes vertex coordinates, there is an offset to the them that are given in the `BufferView& bview` (BufferViews), so I will need to use `bview.byteOffset` somehow to determine the location of the vertices in the buffer.

Thank you so much if you can help me out !

Comment: Keep in mind you'll need to look at the `accessors` as well.  For example, in a given mesh primitive, you may find `"POSITION"` with a number that is an index into the array of `accessors`, and the accessor tells you how to slice the appropriate data out of the `bufferView`.

Comment: Yes, it would be the `acess.ByteStride`